# Connecting images from SQL

Tags: php, html, sql

Every time I try and load the page below the images do not show. I have the image names in an SQL database and also have the image folder in the same path as my index.php.

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h2 class="text-center">Products</h2>

                    <?php

                    $query = "SELECT * FROM product";
                    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {?>
                        <form method="get" action="index.php?id=<?= $row['id'] ?>">
                            <img src="img/<?= $row['image'] ?>" style='height: 150px;'>
                            <h2><?= $row['name']; ?></h2>
                            <h2><?= $row['price']; ?></h2>

                        </form>


                    <?php }


                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h2 class="text-center">Shopping Cart</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are there any errors? Have you done a var_dump($row); To see if the data is there? What does the html look like?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code on my computer and the image appears perfectly.

Perhaps, you forgot to place a connection query.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2 class="text-center">Products</h2>

                <?php

                $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test');

                
                $query = "SELECT * FROM product";
                $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);

                
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {?>                      
                    <form method="get" action="index.php?id=<?= $row['id'] ?>">
                        <img src="img/<?= $row['image'] ?>" style='height: 150px;'>
                        <h2><?= $row['name']; ?></h2>
                        <h2><?= $row['price']; ?></h2>

                    </form>


                <?php }


                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2 class="text-center">Shopping Cart</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```